# Accessing mapping's data from test script

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, testing, unittesting

Suppose there is a mapping `mapping (address => bool) submitted`.
How to access this mapping's data from test script??

Answer (score 0):

for accessing mapping from outside there is two ways.

1. you can make your mapping visibilty to public and solidity automaticly creat a getter function for it e.g `mapping (address => bool) public submitted` and you can access it like this :

   `const isSubmited = await Contract.submitted(myAddress)`
2. you can create getter function for it by your self e.g

```
mapping (address => bool) submitted;
 
 function getSubmitted(address myAddress) public returns(bool){
     return submitted[myAddress];
 }
```

and you can access it same before `const isSubmited = await Contract.getSubmitted(myAddress)`

both do the same.